# SegmentedButtonGroup not changint color inside the listener

Tags: android

I am using this tool to get a toggle button behavior, this is the library:

https://github.com/ceryle/SegmentedButton

I want the left and right buttons to have different colors when selected. When I change the color programmatically, it works fine except from inside the listener, any hin on why this would happen?

```
    SegmentedButtonGroup toggle = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.my_toggle);
    toggle.setSelectorColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
    toggle.setRippleColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
    toggle.setOnPositionChanged(new SegmentedButtonGroup.OnPositionChanged() {
        @Override
        public void onPositionChanged(int position) {
            SegmentedButtonGroup toggle = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.my_toggle);
            toggle.setSelectorColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            toggle.setRippleColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        }
    });
```

I am also open to other implementations of this functionality, I am having a hard time with this...

Comment: have you tried to use the external `toggle` variable instead of using an internal `toggle` variable ?

Comment: Yes, same result :(

Comment: when you run this code, the color that appears on application, is the first one that you have added?

Comment: Yes, the color is green, it is correctly initialized. It is not updated when the position changes (although the code inside the onPositionChanged is effectively executed, with no effect).

Comment: I think this can be a limitation of the lib. But i'm not sure.

Comment: A solution for this issue could be to make your custom view.

Comment: What do you mean? Downloading the source code of the library and modifying it?

Comment: you can do that, or you can make your custom view inside the project.

Comment: A custom view that replicates the behavior of the library but without using the library?

Comment: yes, but more simple, applying to your necessite.

Comment: Thank you very much, I guess I will do that, because a I cannot find a library doing the work..

Comment: I think this is the best to do.